# Custom UITableViewCell with nil UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I created a `UITableView` and this is my code for it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    // let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "SubjectCell")

    let cell = SubjectCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "SubjectCell")

    cell.cellUIImage.image = UIImage(named: "menu.png")

    // cell.cellUIImage = UIImageView(UIImage(named: "menu-32.png"))

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
```

And my `SubjectCell` class is the following:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SubjectCell : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var cellUIImage: UIImageView!
}
```

However, when I run this code, it crashes. Debugging, I noticed that cellUIImage is nil, so it crashes when it unwraps it. The `IBOulet` is linked to my prototype cell.

[image: linked UIImageView]

The unwrapping thing is made by Xcode, and it shouldn't be nil because it is actually a cell `UIImageView`.

Comment: Why aren't you properly dequeuing the cell from the table view?

Comment: @rmaddy no reason in particular. This is a really primitive code, i usually tailor it afterwards... however, I fell this is not the reason why it's crashing.

Comment: It's exactly the reason it fails. Your code doesn't create a cell from your xib/storyboard. You are only creating your cell from code. Therefore none of the outlets of the cell are setup. Properly create your cell. Properly register the cell class/nib and it will work as expected.

Comment: How do I create the cell from the storyboard? I thought with the identifier it should suffice

Comment: You should be using the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: , for:)` method in `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)`. There are plenty of examples of how to dequeue reusable cells on the web.

Comment: That was the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Since the release of iOS storyboard design, you no longer have to subclass `UITableViewCell` to create your custom cell.

In your storyboard, select the Prototype Cell, in the Attributes Inspector tab, give the custom cell an `identifier` (for example: "YourCellIdentifier").

Next, (still in storyboard) select the UIImageView that you added to the custom cell, give it a tag number (for example: 1000)

Now add this code to `cellForRowAt` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    // Here is your desired image view.
    UIImageView *yourImageView = [cell viewWithTag:1000];

    return cell;
}
```